# Is there a faster way to extract elements in a list?

Tags: python, list

suppose I have the list `E = [1,2,1,4,5,4]`, and I want to extract the 2nd, 3rd and 5th element in `E`, let `A = [2,3,5]`, is there a faster way I can get the elements? I tried `E[A]` but it doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: `new_E = [E[i] for i in A]`

Comment: If speed really matters, you could use numpy arrays (in which `E[A]` would work as you hoped)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
E = [1,2,1,4,5,4]
A = [2,3,5]

nE = [ E[a] for a in A ]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `itemgetter` function from the `operator` module may do what you want:

```
from operator import itemgetter
E = [1,2,1,4,5,4]
A = [2,3,5]
print(itemgetter(*A)(E))
```

But you might need a different class altogether depending on the specifics of your speed needs.